# Get x button events in mutter window manager

Tags: mouseevent, x11, xlib

I'm trying to handle Button Events from `XEvent`. My window manager is `mutter`. I added a button on my window, but whenever I click that button, I am getting the `PropertyNotify` signal instead of `ButtonPress`.

I tried grabbing the button events using `XIGrabButton()` but that blocks my UI running on mutter. I tried masking the Events `XI_ButtonPress` and `XI_ButtonRelease` using `XISetMask()` and then I tried to grab the button events but it is not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't (at least directly, without sitting in the middle between client and server). From x11 protocol spec:

```
Multiple clients can select input on the same window; their event-masks are
disjoint. When an event is generated, it will be reported to all interested
clients. However, only one client at a time can select for SubstructureRedirect
, only one client at a time can select for ResizeRedirect, and only one client
at a time can select for ButtonPress. An attempt to violate these restrictions
results in an Access error.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am running `xoo` simulator on `DISPLAY=0.0`(having x window manager) and my mutter on `DISPLAY=1.0`. I want to get the signals for the xoo window...for mutter i am getting the events and I don't want to disturb that.Whatever I will click on `xoo` i will get it as a XEvents. So I need to grab those events in my mutter plugin by getting the window of `xoo`. Is this possible? If it is then how can I achieve this? Please do help me